# Is there a way to use input data/variables for testing keyboard input with pynput keyboard

Tags: python

I'm wondering if i can use a variable to change the key that it:

```
if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
```

is detecting, such as:

```
variable = 'x'
if keyboard.is_pressed(variable):
```

Answer (score 0):

After some testing i have concluded that my problem was that pynput really only wants to read the keyboard.is_pressed() line if the key in question is using '' and not "" hopefully this helped anyone else with this problem